# How can i perform validation on uploaded file in django

Tags: python, django, forms, file-upload

I am uploading the pdf file in django form.

But i need to perform the validation on the pdf file by reading the contents of file and then checking and if its not valid then give some error message.

But i am not able to find how can i get the pdf file location so that i can read the file and do some test.

I don't want to first save in temp location and then do validation and then delete the file

all i need is the path of the file so that i can run some system command on the file

Comment: You will have to save it first in order to get a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below is based on the [Basic file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) example in the django docs. You can have a function in this example called check_pdf that does your validation on the pdf file and returns true/false based on whether it is valid. Depending on that you redirect the user to a success or invalid pdf page. This is the simplest way of doing it. You could do more and present specific error messages using the forms apis.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if check_pdf(request.FILES['file'].name):
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid_pdf/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```